# meaning of {$ ViewName-Index } in Asp.net MVC Code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I was reviewing an ASP.Net Code, in the html code of a page there was something like this

```
<div>{$ViewName-Index}</div>
```

And in run time this piece of code was replacing with Contents of a View in Folder name "ViewName" and file index.cshtml. 
My question is how these two ("{$ViewName-Index}" and "ViewName>index.cshtml file") posibly connected to each other and how does this work? 
Thanks.

Comment: The $ prefix denotes a variable, parameter, property, or method that belongs to the AngularJS component of the app. Look in the AngularJS script and you will find a variable or property with the name `ViewName-Index`

Comment: @JuliusDepulla I checked there isn't any reference to AngularJS, I'm pretty sure AnglurJs hasn't use in this.

Comment: It could be that they want to use C# 6.0 synthax. See examples here http://tinyurl.com/zq5v8ba